# How to map over array of dissimilar objects and return JSX without Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React will throw an error if you map over an array of objects that have different data. I need to figure out how to map over each object and return jsx even if the objects are of different structures.

View this code as an example. It would throw an error.

```js
const data = [{ a: 'a-data',  b: 'b-data' },  { a: 'a-data' }];
const elements = data.map(d => {
  
    return <div key={d.val}> <p>{d.a}</p><p>{d.b}</div>;
});
return <div>{elements}</div>;
```

I should be able to see two p tags for the first object, and only one p tag for the second.

Comment: I don't think it does cause an error. The only error I see is you have not closed the second `p` tag as @JordanRunning has said below

Comment: You forgot to close your last `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring with default arguments.

For example:

```js
const data = [{ a: 'a-data',  b: 'b-data' },  { a: 'a-data' }];
const elements = data.map(({a, b} = {}, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>{a}</p>
        <p>{b}</p>
      </div>
    );
});
ReactDOM.render(<div>{elements}</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it actually doesn't throw an error. I was confusing the "cannot read prop type "someName" of undefined" error with what I had described here.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  
  render(){
    const data = [{ a: 'a-dataOne',  b: 'b-dataOne', c:"hljkdflj" },  { a: 'a-data' }];
const elements = data.map(d => {
  
  return <div key={d.val}> <p>{d.a}</p><p>{d.b}</p><p>{d.c}</p></div>;
});
return <div>{elements}</div>;
    
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp></MyApp>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```